# Do I need to mandatorily install Windows 8 immediately while purchasing an upgrade?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

Microsoft has an ongoing launch offer / upgrade offer for existing users of Windows 7 to upgrade to Windows 8 for INR 2,000 (~USD $50). This can be availed via the Windows 8 Upgrade Advisor app.

Here's my question- If I opt to purchase the upgrade, do I also need to install it immediately or will I be given a product key that I can use at a later time? I believe this upgrade offer is time-bound and will be valid up to some time in JAN 2013.

Comment: The time limitation is only for the **purchase** of the upgrade. After they have your money and you have an order receipt, there is no more time limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can upgrade at any time after you purchase it.

When you purchase it, you can download the upgrade software, as well as get the product key. After that, when you actually do the upgrade is up to you. (After all, Microsoft isn't worried when you upgrade - they've already made the money off you).

Comment: +10000 for the last line :P

Comment: I'm more concerned about being forced to go thru with the upgrade by the Upgrade Assistant program.

Comment: @Sparx: The Upgrade Assistant allows you to create bootable USB/DVD (ISO) media, which you can use later any time on any PC (obviously you need separate keys though).

Comment: @Karan - any idea of the size of USB drive that would be needed/recommended? Would a 4GB pen drive suffice?